# Database, api or webservice to host small number of messages, start level noob

Tags: android, database, web-services, webserver

I have been able to avoid database, webserver setting 20 years, but now I face it. I found so much information that I rather ask before messing all around with a broken system.

So, I need to host about 10 discussions that have about 25 messages each, older I want to remove. So this is really light weighted. My first idea is to have data in JSON format only because I have some experience on that. Data will be accessed from android application.

Now I have been boiling my brains with, mongodb, micro_httpd, libmicrohttpd, json-server, nginx, nosql, nodes, mariadb, mongodb... and it is time to make decisions.

While data is accessed from android application I wonder do I even need any webserver, actually, I dont necessary want that people can browse to host and read everything from browser. Idea is to use example Get to get sender, subject, message into android textviews and same to opposite direction. Thats why I started to think some api or database that can be connected from internet, but webserver is also ok, if stuff can be hided.

This is not a tutorial place, but if someone with experience could propose some setup for me and directions? I have googled pretty much all tutorials. In first setup I would be happy just to receive and send messages to database/api/webserver/webservice, but later on it would also be nice to have some authentication, and one important, somepoint there will be spam coming anyway and I read something about putting sender ip address five minutes to halt. Captcha would be very appreciated, I guess I could open one in android webview. And from our team leader, apache is not an option while it can leak some information (though I didnt see that dangerous). And to remind, this seems something really light.

Answer (score 0):

I think Firebase is the best solution for you: easy to use, no server database complications, easy to implement. Watch some up-to-date videos from the web and you are set.